# Python Numpy 2d array slicing minus index to plus index

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to slice the array so that the last value is followed by the first value.

Code :

```py
import numpy as np

arr = [[1, 2, 3, 4], 
       [5, 6, 7, 8], 
       [9, 10, 11, 12], 
       [13, 14, 15, 16]]

m = np.array(arr)

print(m[-1:1, -1:1])
```

expected output :

```py
[[16 13]
 [4 1]]
```

actual output :

```py
[]
```

Comment: The `-1:1` notation is a slice, you're trying to use an index. Those are two different things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use advanced indexing:

```
In [64]: arr=np.arange(1,17).reshape(4,4)   
In [65]: arr[[[3],[0]],[3,0]]       # or -1 as in mozway's answer
Out[65]: 
array([[16, 13],
       [ 4,  1]])
```

On further thought, you can use a -3 step:

```
In [67]: arr[-1::-3, -1::-3]
Out[67]: 
array([[16, 13],
       [ 4,  1]])
```

The numbers and shape are the same, but `strides` is different (one is a copy, the other a view (with somewhat funny strides):

```
In [69]: arr[[[-1],[0]],[-1,0]].strides
Out[69]: (8, 4)
In [70]: arr[-1::-3, -1::-3].strides
Out[70]: (-48, -12)
```

Comment: I'm afraid going into the strides might be much. I think OP need to read again the python slicing/indexing basics (+1) ;)

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to create a mesh. Don't use a slice.

You can use [`ix_`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html#numpy.ix_) as a convenience:

```
m[np.ix_([-1, 1], [-1, 1])]
```

Output:

```
array([[16, 14],
       [ 8,  6]])
```

Or, if you want the first index use `0` (not `1`):

```
m[np.ix_([-1, 0], [-1, 0])]
```

Output:

```
array([[16, 13],
       [ 4,  1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this solution :

```
import numpy as np

arr = [[1, 2, 3, 4], 
       [5, 6, 7, 8], 
       [9, 10, 11, 12], 
       [13, 14, 15, 16]]

m = np.array(arr)

print(m[0:len(m):len(m)-1, 0:len(m):len(m)-1][::-1, ::-1])
```

Probably not the best, but working.